# How to change the mode of trial purchases to real purchases in Android inApp billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have my app with InApp Billing and I'm using [Android In-App Billing v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)
 in billing mode billing works well, but I do not know how to go into production mode and make real purchases.

my code is the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.pubKey), this); //R.string.pubKey contain my license key from play.console
    bp.initialize();
    purchaseBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_purchaseItem);
    purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, "get_10_coins", getResources().getString(R.string.pubKey));//This product id is registered and active in the play console.
            bp.consumePurchase("get_10_coins"); 
        }
    });
}
```

when I click to buy in my application, the following comes out:
[image]

but I can not make a real purchase, **how can I switch from trial mode to production mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your email in Google Play Console >> Settings >> Manage Testers

Comment: I have already removed it, but the same thing is still happening. :(

Comment: Check your tester list in Google Play Console >> Your App >> Release Management >> App Releases >> Manage (Alpha, Beta) >> Manage Testers. It will take some time to refresh.